# How to change the width or height of a tkinter entry field

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been making a script for checking grammar. Now I've updated it to be in a gui using Tkinter. The problem is that I'm trying to indicate the row where the grammar is wrong, and when I use an entry field to input the text everything is in one row.

**My question is how do you expand the entry field?**

This is my code:

```
import re
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.minsize(width=300, height= 20)
wr = []

def work():
    x = e1.get()
    print(x)
    BigLetterSearcher = re.compile(r'\. .|\n')
    mo = BigLetterSearcher.findall(e1.get())
    x = 1
    y = 0
    v = 0
    z = ""
    wr = []
    for i in mo:
        if i == '\n':
            x += 1
        elif i != i.upper():
            v = 1
            if x != y:
                z = "Row", x
                wr.append(z)
            wr.append(i)
            y = x
    if v == 0:
        wr.append ("Congratulations none of your grammar was wrong!")
    l1.configure(text=wr)

l1 = Label(window, text="example")
e1 = Entry(window, text="Enter text here: ")
b1 = Button(window, text="Work", command=work)

leb = [l1, e1, b1]
for all in leb:
    all.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You cannot expand the height of an entry field. Use the text widget instead. For the width all you need to specify is `width=some_number_here` when setting up the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry widget is not capable of being expanded vertically. This is because there is already a widget designed for this and that is called `Text()`. For adding text to the text widget we can use `insert()` and you specify where with a 2 part index. The first part is the row and the 2nd is the column. For the row/line it starts at number 1 and for the index of that row it starts at zero.

For example if you wish to insert something at the very first row/column you would do `insert("1.0", "some data here")`.

Here is you code with the use of `Text()` instead.

```
import re
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.minsize(width=300, height= 20)
wr = []

def work():
    x = e1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(x)
    BigLetterSearcher = re.compile(r'\. .|\n')
    mo = BigLetterSearcher.findall(x)
    x = 1
    y = 0
    v = 0
    z = ""
    wr = []
    for i in mo:
        if i == '\n':
            x += 1
        elif i != i.upper():
            v = 1
            if x != y:
                z = "Row", x
                wr.append(z)
            wr.append(i)
            y = x
    if v == 0:
        wr.append ("Congratulations none of your grammar was wrong!")
    l1.configure(text=wr)

l1 = Label(window, text="example")
e1 = Text(window, width=20, height=3)
e1.insert("end", "Enter text here: ")
b1 = Button(window, text="Work", command=work)

leb = [l1, e1, b1]
for all in leb:
    all.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: your code is working up to the step were it grabs the text from the text field

    x = e1.get()

Here it gives us the error:

    t.py", line 1699, in call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "C:/Users/Moltas/Desktop/programering/Gemensamma_projekt/1.py", line 9, in 
    work
    x = e1.get()
    TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Comment: I only added the text field. I didn't bother checking your code. Let me check.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding an Entry field vertically can only be done by changing the size of the font associated with the Entry field...

```
e1 = Entry(window, text="Enter text here: ", font=('Ubuntu', 24))
```

results in a taller Entry field than

```
e1 = Entry(window, text="Enter text here: ", font=('Ubuntu', 12))
```